# Numpy.asarray method behaves differently on OS X and Ubuntu

Tags: arrays, macos, numpy, ubuntu-11.10

I have a function that fills a list of lists and return a numpy array by the asarray method.

```
L = [[],[],[],[],[],[],[]]
# put some data in L
myarray = asarray(L)
```

The function nicely works as it ought do under OS X, giving a ndarray with shape=(7,). 
Under Ubuntu the *very same* code gives a zero-Rank numpy array with shape=(). However, I can recover the saved data by calling

```
myarray[()] or myarray[()].[i]
```

that indicates that myarray is a list instead. Indeed

```
In [32]: type(myarray)
Out[32]: <type 'numpy.ndarray'>

In [33]: type(myarray[...])
Out[33]: <type 'numpy.ndarray'>

In [34]: type(myarray[()])
Out[34]: <type 'list'>
```

I've been completely disoriented  by  that. Any hints of what is going on?

Comment: Really "put some data in L" is **not** useful, because it makes all the difference.

Comment: @seberg I fill one by one the lists in a for loop.

Comment: With what, how many items, are you sure you don't have a bug... you will have to give some exact info. Oh and also the numpy versions...

Comment: @seberg If I would have a bug I should see it also in OS X. I would like to give exact info, but it's a pretty long story to tell, after filling the lists I have the same object in OS X as in Ubuntu, the problem arises after calling numpy.asarray; Anyway, I run numpy 1.6.1 in OS X and numpy 1.5.1 in Ubuntu, could be this the problem?

Comment: @seberg Thank you **very** much for moving the attention to the numpy version! After updating numpy it works without problems!!! Thanks again

Comment: If your lists were of the same length, you would get a an array of shape (7, N), so i still somewhat wonder if you are not doing something not quite right...

Comment: @seberg my lists are not of the same length :) Thanks for wondering.